# What happens to the provisioner "shell-local" from packer when we run it on windows

Tags: windows, multiplatform, packer

i am talking about this provisioner: https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell-local.html.

I am running a packer build that uses a vagrant base box (debian/jessie64) so i need to download vagrant and download that base box. But i need this packer build to run the same in windows.

So how does windows treats the shell-local provisioner can i just do:

```
        "provisioners": [
          {"type": "shell-local",
              "command": "vagrant box add --name debian-vagrant-development box/modified-debian-VAGRANTSLASH-jessie64"},
          {"type": "shell",
              "inline": ["echo 'my additional provisioning steps'"]}
              ],
```

Which i am pretty sure i can't, and in that case; which is the alternative?, do i just make this in ansible and put packer to run it.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? I am not clear on _running a packer build that uses a vagrant base box_ The job of packer is to create a box to be used by vagrant, you add the box to vagrant **after** it is created (so everything has been run, including provisioners).

Comment: Yes the vagrant box is added after it is created but is added with a specific command with a specific argument "--name" so that the Vagrantfile is usable.
And before the box is created i need to follow some specific commands which i think are just a part of the automation we are trying to do. So what i am trying to do is automate those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too big of a task for what it actually accomplish, is not really practical for my use case. In the case is needed i'll say use ansible or chef or what you use for provision to keep the portability. Thank you.